# SendKeys.SendWait("^c") problem

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to copy selected text in active application from my application in background. I use SendKeys.SendWait(). But i have a problem sometimes: after a while my application sends only "c" without "CTRL" (at least only "c" comes to active application).

Anybody can help?

thanks in advise....

Comment: Check the docs for SendKeys, it talks about altering the .config file to use another method to send keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you drop the `SendKeys` all together, as it is a recipe for failure.  There are too many events that can happen between the time you copy, activate a window, and paste your data.

I believe one of the best ways to accomplish your task would be to use the [SendMessage API](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SendMessage), which you can interop into your project.

Instead of activating an application and sending via SendKeys, you can essentially hook the handle of the textbox in the external application and set the target equal to the string you wish to paste.  This will guarantee the data you are attempting to send to the application will get there, regardless of any other windows that popup or focus during the operation.

I would look at this tutorial, which already has classes built to help you post your data.

[c-win32-messaging-with-sendmessage-and-wm_copydata](http://boycook.wordpress.com/2008/07/29/c-win32-messaging-with-sendmessage-and-wm_copydata/)

Comment: But I want to get selected text from external application. I don't need to paste text.

Comment: @Glum - This is a general method -- you can send whatever messages you need.  If the text is in an edit control, take a look at [Edit Control (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775458.aspx#messages) for a list of messages, particularly `EM_GETLINE`, `EM_GETSEL`.

Comment: It will not be work with all application (for example Acrobat Reader) But my approach will work with all applications that support CTRL + C keystroke

Comment: This is not very likely to work, SendMessage() cannot alter the keyboard state of the process.  Which is important here, lots of programs use it to check if the modifier keys are active.  Like Ctrl, Shift and Alt.  The tutorial you linked talks about WM_COPYDATA, that doesn't have anything to do with the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

try
**SendKeys.Send("^c");**
it works for me :)