# How to close browers tab with wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to close current active tab of any browser like chrome, firefox, opera etc
Currently I am using this `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("^W");` (pressing "control" + "w" which is shortkey for closing current tab) But problem is instead of close current tab it is closing all tabs along with browser
what am I doing wrong
If there is another way to achieve this then please tell me

Comment: Are you sure your application is only sending the Ctrl+W one time? Did you debug your application? Can you run your application on another application that simply outputs the keys and modifiers (I don't know if snoop can do that for instance)?

Comment: yes my application is only sending the Ctrl+W one time checked on keylogger software

Comment: I'm thinking it might be that the browser never register the "key up" state, I'm not sure how you would go about sending that state, I thought SendKeys would do that for you..

Comment: What happens if you use the `Send` method instead, and not the `SendWait` method?

Comment: `Send` gives error   
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: SendKeys cannot run inside this application because the application is not handling Windows messages.  Either change the application to handle messages, or use the SendKeys.SendWait method.

Comment: Might this help; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736704/sendkeys-sendwaitc-problem ?